# How to pass variable name to a function and get it available outside in bash?

Tags: bash, macos, variables, scope

How can I pass a variable name to a function and use it outside its scope?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
questionPrompt() {
    while [ -z "$answer" ]; do
    echo $1
    read answer
    ${2}=$answer
    done
}

questionPrompt "Which color do you like?" "COLOR"

echo $COLOR
```

It says: `COLOR=red: command not found`

Comment: Why would you want to create a function that does exactly the same thing as `read -p "question" answervar`?

Comment: Because I want to verify user input just one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `declare`:

```
declare -g "$2=$answer"
```

or

```
declare -gn var=$2
var="$answer"
```

However, the version of `bash` that ships with macOS (3.2) doesn't support `declare -g`; you can use `printf` instead.

```
printf -v "$2" '%s' "$answer"
```

Comment: It seems to work but it put me on exit and I can run anymore any other function call e.g. `questionPrompt "Which color do you like?" "SIZE"`

Comment: `answer` is global as well, so the second time you call it, `answer` is already non-empty, so the loop is never entered. Add `local answer` as the first line of the function.